# Image views in list views

Tags: android, listview, imageview, listactivity

I am trying to insert an image in `ListView` and when I click on it to display the image in a new image view (Bigger View).

I don't have an Android phone to execute my application.

This is my ImageViewer class.

```java
public class ImageViewer extends ListActivity {

   Uri uri;
   Cursor c;
   ListView l;
   ArrayList<String> al1 = new ArrayList<String>();
   ArrayList<String> al2 = new ArrayList<String>();
   int data, dname;
   String dt, disnam, imgid;
   int id;
   String type;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      uri = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;
      String project[] = {MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA,
            MediaStore.Images.Media._ID};
      c = getContentResolver().query(uri, project, null, null, null);
      data = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
      dname = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME);
      id = c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);

      if (c.moveToFirst()) {
         do {
            dt = c.getString(data);
            disnam = c.getString(dname);
            imgid = c.getString(id);
            al1.add(dt);
            al2.add(disnam);
         } while (c.moveToNext());
      }
      l = getListView();
      l.setAdapter(new MyAdapter());
      l.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

         @Override
         public void onItemClick(
               AdapterView<?> arg0,
               View arg1, int arg2, long arg3
         ) {

            String filename = al1.get(arg2);
            Intent intent = new Intent(ImageViewer.this, Viewer.class);
            intent.putExtra("image2view", filename);
            intent.putExtra("type", type);
            intent.putExtra("id", id);
            startActivity(intent);
         }
      });
   }


   public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

      @Override
      public int getCount() {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public Object getItem(int arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return null;
      }

      @Override
      public long getItemId(int arg0) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         return 0;
      }

      @Override
      public View getView(int pos, View convertview, ViewGroup vg) {
         // TODO Auto-generated method stub


         View row = convertview;
         if (row == null) {
            LayoutInflater inf = getLayoutInflater();
            row = inf.inflate(R.layout.image, vg, false);
         }

         TextView filename = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.ImageName);
         filename.setText(al2.get(pos) + "\n");

         ImageView thumbs = (ImageView) row.findViewById(R.id.Thumb);
         thumbs.setImageResource(id);
         thumbs.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
         thumbs.setPadding(8, 8, 28, 8);

         return row;
      }
   }
}
```

This is my Viewer class, which has to display the selected image in full screen.

```java
public class Viewer extends Activity{
    
    ImageView iv;
    TextView tv;
    public void onCreate(Bundle b1){
        super.onCreate(b1);
        
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        
        setContentView(R.layout.imageview);
                System.gc();
                
        Bundle b2=getIntent().getExtras();
        //String file=b2.getString("image2view");
        int id=b2.getInt("id");
        
        iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView101);
        iv.setImageResource(id);
        getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,
                R.layout.help_title);
        ImageView iv = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.header);
        iv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                new Intent();
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The xml file used for `ImageViewer` class is image.xml.

```xml
<RelativeLayout 
    android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout02" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/mainbkgnd" 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/Thumb"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>

    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/Thumb" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:id="@+id/ImageName"
        android:text="Image Name"
        android:textColor="#000000">
    </TextView>
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

The xml code for the Viewer class is imageview.xml.

```xml
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
    android:id="@+id/itextView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:visibility="gone" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView101"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.62"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    
</LinearLayout>
```

I searched but I couldn't find suitable code.

Comment: nikz when u are getting error or what happen when u are running this code make question more clear

Comment: @imran actually the application that i'm creating takes in a voice input from the user.."images" or "gallery" and then opens all the images in the cell phone....there are no errors, but i cant take a voice input from the pc....i don't have an android phone to run it and find out if this code is working...its for my mini project in B.tech

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe that this `id`:

```
id=c.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.Media._ID);
```

Is the appropriate resource `id` for:

```
iv.setImageResource(id);
```

You should be able to do this in Viewer's onCreate() instead:

```
String filename = b2.getString("filename");
if(filename != null)
    iv.setImageUri(Uri.fromFile(new File(filename)));
```

Comment: will this automatically set the image in the image view ??

Comment: this is the change i have made so far in Viewer activity

Bundle b2=getIntent().getExtras();  
  String filename=b2.getString("image2view");  
  //int id=b2.getInt("id");  
  if(filename!=null)  
  {  
   iv=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView101);  
   iv.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(new File(filename)));  
  }

Comment: while running it over the pc...no errors as of that particular activity...i debugged it...but i dont have an android phone to run it into.

Comment: If it runs in an emulator _most of the time_ it will run on a real device. If I have solved your question please click the checkmark in the upper-right of my answer.

Comment: My application is a voice based one...so whenever i say "images" or "gallery", all the images in the mobile have to be displayed in a list view. run time allocation of the list view with images.....the problem is...this app can only be run on the mobile...bcos a laptop or pc cannot take the voice input....and I dont have an android mobile to run my app

Comment: done :)...thank u so much...i would have even rated your answer but im new to stackoverflow, my reputation is 0 and infact this is the first question i have posted here :P....but thanks anyway...in a day's time i'll surely try to execute this over an android phone somehow

Comment: @imrankhan I'm glad you didn't take my comments as an attack, I was only trying to say Nikz had already done most of what you suggested, but I could finish replying after you removed it... Thanks for the upvote! And you're welcome Nikz!

Comment: im surely gonna do a +1 once my reputation reaches 15...but thank u guys...both of u...sam and imran....hoping to catch up with you in case my project shows up some errors

Comment: I forgot to ask about the permissions that i have to give for accessing the images in gallery of the phone

Comment: The permissions requirements for an emulator and a device are the same. So no, I don't know of any required permissions.